How to setup Vite in Angular after using Webpack
After updating to Angular 18 and choosing Vite as the Build tool, some packages are not resolved, i.e.:
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "@angular/common/http"

    ../../../../http-options.ts:1:27:
      1 │ import { HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";
        ╵                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "@angular/common/http" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

The problem is, I have two projects and two package.json files, one was referencing the other packages with the help of the tsconfig.json file:
"paths": {
      "@angular/*":  [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ],

I installed "vite-tsconfig-paths" and added a vite.config.ts file. But it didn't solve the problem. I also added the resolve alias to the vite config.
Most of all I would just like to know if it is possible. Or even better, if there is another way to set it up.

Would creating a new branch to preserve your changes, then remove these "paths" in both your projects and try npm link method, I am assuming you have a project and a application that uses this project.
Make sure you have "preserveSymlinks": true set in angular.json, for all the projects that use linking.
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ...
        "preserveSymlinks": true,

This tutorial is good for working with linked packages.
How to Develop Angular Libraries Locally?

It sounds like an interesting idea and I will consider using link in the future. But no, this is not my use case. The way these two projects are connected is the first is using the second as a component library and importing it as an Angular module.
